# Jenkins Build Name Status

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a deploy job that has a prerequisite that another job being successfully run with the latest git hash.

Is it possible to check for that condition and then run the prerequisite job if the condition is not met?

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain this information using Jenkins' REST API:

http://JENKINS-HOST:8080/job/JOB-NAME/lastBuild/api/xml

Git commit hash is under SHA1 node and status under result node. You can use jenkins pipeline in order to run this job if the status is not SUCCESS.

Comment: The job is generic and can be used for different accounts/apps. I need to verify that a specific account/app/commit combo was successful.